# jQuery Draggable reset position with double click

Tags: jquery, css, html, html4

I am a bit stuck with this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6kXTP/1/). When the user drags the square that's all working fine. But when the user double clicks the square after dragging it away from the original position i want it to return to the original position which is only half working (vertically). It is not going to the right!
Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: Your example doesn't do anything. Please correct it first -- at first glance, the id's in your jQuery don't match the HTML id's at all.

Comment: Dragging an item sets the "left" property on the div, which conflicts with "right". You'll need to make your js set the CSS of the left property, or remove it on dblClick.

Answer (score 0):

you could do (i corrected your fiddle because it was totally wrong):

```
jQuery("#drag_item").draggable({containment: '#container'});
var position = jQuery("#drag_item").position();
//you could also use 
//var position = jQuery("#drag_item").offset();

$("#drag_item").dblclick(function() {



    $('#drag_item').css({
        'top': position.top
    });

    $('#drag_item').css({
        'position': 'fixed'
    });
    $('#drag_item').css({
        'left': position.left
    });
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/6kXTP/5/

Comment: I think in this case, he'll want to use `offset()` instead of `position()` to find its position relative to the document: http://api.jquery.com/offset/ ( http://jsfiddle.net/6kXTP/20/ )